# Associating Facebook Login with an already logged-in account

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api

I already saw this [documentation by facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers#addingfacebook) regarding this case. But it really does not said anything about how to solve the issue.

**My case is that**

1. I already have an existing user logged in using a custom log in system (Laravel authentication).
2. Now, I want it to link to a facebook account(same email address), so that I can get an access token from it. And use in other API calls.

**The problem**

1. I do not know how to get the `access_token` from the facebook-graph-api if the user logged in using the custom log in system.

**What I Have so far**

1. I created a new table `SNS_user_facebok` with the following columns:

   - id
   - user_id
   - facebook_email
2. Whenever the user logged in using facebook, I associate the email address to the corresponding email in the `users` table. I plan to add this association in somewhere like `user->settings->add_fb_link` somewhere in the program.

Comment: _“I do not know how to get the access_token from the facebook-graph-api if the user logged in using the custom log in system.”_ - same way as you would _always_ get it - by sending the user through the Facebook login flow. This has nothing whatsoever to do with whether the user is already logged in to your custom system, or not.

Comment: Be aware though, that you will likely not be able to _get_ an email address for every Facebook user - they might not have one set up at all (registered to FB using mobile only), some obscure privacy settings can still prevent the API from returning it even if the user grants permission - or they might simply be using a different email for Facebook, then they used for your system. If you make sure they logged in using your system first, you should have no problem with associating the token and/or user id with the correct account, without relying on the email.

Comment: @misorude , this means that the user needs to login again using the facebook login flow? It is quite redundant if the user logs in using the custom login using email and password then I need to ask the user again to authenticate himself using facebook...

Comment: At least the first time they need to do this actively; on recurring visits, the Facebook JS SDK can be used to recognize them again automatically once they visit your site (if they are logged in to Facebook in their browser at the time.)